# AWK replace null column with the column value of next row

Tags: shell, awk

I have following sample file with missing column values for which I would like to replace with next available value from same column.

```
cat test.txt
11.2.0.1,ORA1,ORACLE
11.2.0.4,ORA2,ORACLE
11.2.0.3,ORA3,ORACLE
12.2.0.1,ORA4,ORACLE
,ORA5,ORACLE
,ORA6,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA7,ORACLE
,MYS1,MYSQL
5.1,MYS2,MYSQL
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 cat test.txt |awk '{printf("%s,%s,%s\n", $11,$3,$1);}'|awk -F',' 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
   {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i=="")
            --Read next column value
            --If next column is null, read futhur next
            -- Assign next available value to $i
        print
    }'
```

Expected output:

```
11.2.0.1,ORA1,ORACLE
11.2.0.4,ORA2,ORACLE
11.2.0.3,ORA3,ORACLE
12.2.0.1,ORA4,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA5,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA6,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA7,ORACLE
5.1,MYS1,MYSQL
5.1,MYS2,MYSQL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
awk -F, '$1==""{a[n++]=$0;next} n{for (i=0;i<n;i++) print $1 a[i]; n=0} 1' file
```

details:

```
$1=="" {          # if the first field is empty
    a[n++]=$0     # store the whole line at index n and increment n
    next          # jump to the next line
}

n {                    # if n isn't zero
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)  # loop over stored lines indexes
        print $1 a[i]  # and print lines starting with the current first field
    n=0                # set n to 0
}

1  # true, print the current line
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
tac file | awk -F, '$1{l=$1} !$1{$1=l} OFS=","' | tac
```

- `tac` is like `cat` but reverses the file line by line.
- `awk -F,` sets the field separator to comma.
- `$1{l=$1}` if the first field `$1` is set, set the `l` variable and print the line
- `!$1{$1=l}` if the first field `$1` is not set, take the value from the `l` variable and print the line.
- `OFS=","`  sets the output field separator to comma.
- `tac` finally reverse the file back.

---

The output:

```
11.2.0.1,ORA1,ORACLE
11.2.0.4,ORA2,ORACLE
11.2.0.3,ORA3,ORACLE
12.2.0.1,ORA4,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA5,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA6,ORACLE
12.2.0.2,ORA7,ORACLE
5.1,MYS1,MYSQL
5.1,MYS2,MYSQL
```

Comment: That would fail if `$1` had a value that awk decided evaluated numerically to zero. You need to test for `$1!=""` and `$1==""`. When you have 2 variables that MUST have the same value (`FS` and `OFS` in this case), don't set them independently to that value at opposite ends of the script, set them together at the front before they are used: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}...`. Never use `l` (the letter `el`) as a variable name as it looks far too much like `1` (the number `one`), indistinguishable in some fonts, and so obfuscates your code.